# Check if the array contains a certain object

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, firebase

I was wondering how i could check if an array contains a certain value after the data is retrieved from firebase. I retrieve the data and store it in an array as follows:

```
    [self.firebase2 observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot){

    if (newMessagesOnTop) {
        [self.chat2 insertObject:snapshot.value atIndex:0];
    } else {
        [self.chat2 addObject:snapshot.value];
    }
```

From here i want to check if there is a particular object in the array chat2. And I also want to know in which particular method should I put it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The answers below are correct. As far as which method to put it in, that's is really up to when you want to look the for the object (based on user action? timed?), However the important piece is that your code will be called once for every child in the node up front, and then called again any time a child is added. You should not look for objects in the array until after the block has been completed for all child objects, which is upon the first time the method is called. You may need a count of those objects to determine when it's done, or perhaps use .Value so they are all loaded in at once.

Answer (score 1):

In Objective-C this is the code

```
NSArray * list = @[@(1),@(2),@(3)];
if ([list containsObject:@(2)]) {
    NSLog(@"Yes");
} else {
    NSLog(@"No");
}
```

Comment: What method should I put it in if I'm using fire base?

Comment: @TejasBadani: Please clarify what you need to know

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if you chat2 already contains the object retrieved you should use containObject() to check if object is present

BOOL isPresent= [self.chat2 containsObject:snapshot.value];

it doesn't matter if you use firebase or any other you are storing the object in an array thats all needed to for operation.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([self.chat2 containsObject:snapshot.value]) {
    [self.chat2 insertObject:snapshot.value atIndex:0];
} else {
    [self.chat2 addObject:snapshot.value];
}
[self setNeedsDisplay];
[tableView reloadData];
```